# react-router v6: get path pattern for current route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is it possible to get the path pattern for the currently matched route? Example:

```
<Route
    path=":state/:city*"
    element={
        <Page />
    }
/>
```

```js
// Page.jsx

function Page() {
    ...
    // usePathPattern doesn't actually exist
    const pathPattern = usePathPattern(); // pathPattern = ":state/:city*"
    ...
}
```

I know I can use `useMatch` to check if the current location matches a specific path pattern, but then the component has to know what the path pattern is.

Answer (score 71):

I made a custom hook `useCurrentPath` with react-router v6 to get the current path of route, and it work for me

If the current pathname is `/members/5566` I will get path `/members/:id`

```js
import { matchRoutes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

const routes = [{ path: "/members/:id" }]

const useCurrentPath = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [{ route }] = matchRoutes(routes, location)

  return route.path
}
```

```
function MemberPage() {
  const currentPath = useCurrentPath() // `/members/5566` -> `/members/:id`
   
  return <></>
}
```

#### Reference

https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#matchroutes

Comment: This worked great for me. The custom hook is a personal preference. However, `useLocation` + `matchRoutes` is the answer.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with nested routes with relative paths. For example, when `location.pathname` is `"/users/123/profile"` but `routes[0].path` is `"profile"` due to being nested under `"users/:id"`. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @eliw00d I had the same issue with nested routes. I solved this by searching the matching routes by the pathname: `matchRoutes(routes, location).find(m => m.pathname === location.pathname)`. This should leave you with the exact route match only, and not the parent routes.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure if it resolves your use case fully but in my case I used combination of `useLocation` and `useParams`. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import type { Location, Params } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * Function converts path like /user/123 to /user/:id
 */
const getRoutePath = (location: Location, params: Params): string => {
  const { pathname } = location;

  if (!Object.keys(params).length) {
    return pathname; // we don't need to replace anything
  }

  let path = pathname;
  Object.entries(params).forEach(([paramName, paramValue]) => {
    if (paramValue) {
      path = path.replace(paramValue, `:${paramName}`);
    }
  });
  return path;
};

export const Foo = (): JSX.Element => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  const path = getRoutePath(location, params);

  (...)
};
```

Comment: This solution would break when parts of the path have the same value, e.g. `/user/1/badge/1/comment/1`. While that's an uncommon scenario, this solution is still not universally reliable.

Comment: Better to use https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#matchroutes instead.

Comment: @HermanJ.RadtkeIII link seems to be broken. Maybe you mean [this](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/utils/match-routes)

Comment: I used the solution above but with:
```path = path.replace(new RegExp(`\\/${paramValue}(\\/|\\?|$)`), `/:${paramName}$1`);```
It's a little safer as it is less likely to cause an erroneous match on another part of the path that happens to match a param value

Comment: @BenBarkay, I'm not sure this is true. Unless you pass the g flag to the replace function, it will only replace the first instance of the match. Since the params entries are enumerated in order, it should successfully substitute even when multiple params have the same value.

The bigger risk was that a param value might accidentally match another part of the path. I've tried to tighten this up with my suggested regex above, which requires the param to start with a / and end with either /, ? or the end of the string.

It's still not bullet proof though.

Answer (score 9):

From within the context of a `Route` you can get the `path` via several methods layed out in [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match).

My issue was slightly different in that I needed the `path` outside the context of the `Route` and came to the below solution that should also work for you:

```
import {
    matchPath,
    useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

const routes = [ ':state/:city', ...otherRoutes ];

function usePathPattern() {

    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    return matchPath( pathname, routes )?.path;
}
```

Comment: Your documentation link points to the v5 docs, not the v6 docs, and is therefore unhelpful.

Comment: Documentation v6: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/utils/match-path

Answer (score 5):

this is works for me easily

first of all import uselocation from react-router-dom

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"
```

then

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location.pathname);
```

Comment: This gives the literal path not the path pattern.

Answer (score 3):

With React Router v6:

```
import { matchPath, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const routes = ["/", "/login", "product", "product/:id"];

const usePathPattern = (): string | undefined => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return routes.find((route) => matchPath(route, pathname));
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this code:

```
import { useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const usePath: any = () => {
  let { pathname } = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  return Object.entries(params).reduce((path: any, [key, value]) => {
    return path.replace(`/${value}`, `/:${key}`);
  }, pathname);
};

export default usePath;
```

enjoy it!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work with what they actually export as of 6.2.1, however it uses a component they export as UNSAFE_

```
import { UNSAFE_RouteContext } from 'react-router-dom';

const reconstructPath = (matches) =>
  matches
    .map(({ route: { path } }) =>
      path.endsWith('/*') ? path.slice(0, -1) : path ? path + '/' : ''
    )
    .join('');

const findLastNode = (node) =>
  node.outlet ? findLastNode(node.outlet.props.value) : node;

const usePathPattern = () =>
  reconstructPath(
    findLastNode(React.useContext(UNSAFE_RouteContext)).matches
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the matched route in react-router v6 you need to use the `matchPath` function.
You will need to store all your routes in a variable like an array.
Then you can loop through all routes and use that function to find the matched route. Carefully as it will match the first truthy value, ideally you need to loop through them in the same order you have rendered them.

> This isn't a perfect solution as it may not handle nested routes unless you store those in the same variable.

Here's an example:

**routes.ts**

```
const routes = [
  { name: 'Home', path: '/home', element: Home },
  { name: 'Profile', path: '/profile', element: Profile },
  { name: '404', path: '*', element: NotFound },
];
```

**App.tsx**

```
<App>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      {routes.map((route, key) => (
        <Route key={key} path={route.path} element={<route.element />} />
      ))}
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</App
```

**useMatchedRoute.tsx**

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router';

export function useMatchedRoute() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  for (const route of routes) {
    if (matchPath({ path: route.path }, pathname)) {
      return route;
    }
  }
}
```

**Header.tsx**

```
export function Header() {
  const route = useMatchedRoute();

  return <div>{route.name}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank [@FutianShen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18287774/futian-shen). But [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265608/react-router-v6-get-path-pattern-for-current-route/71246254#71246254) is incorrect if you have **nested routes**. I tried to fix its issue:

```js
const routes = (
  <Route path='/' element={<Root />}>
    <Route index element={<Index />} />
    <Route path=':orgName' element={<Org />}>
      <Route ...>
        ...
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
)
const appRoutes = createRoutesFromElements(routes)

function usePathPattern() {
  const location = useLocation()
  return useMemo(
    () =>
      matchRoutes(appRoutes, location)
        .map(({ route: { path } }) => path)
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join('/')
        .replaceAll(/\/\*?\//g, '/'),
    [location],
  )
}
```

This also works for **nested routes**.

Sample output:

```
/:orgName/projects/:projectSlug/vms/:vmUid/*
```

---

But if you don't have access to your `appRoutes` object, I don't have any idea except using `UNSAFE_RouteContext` (thank [@RichN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96386/richn)).

I tried to improve/fix [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265608/react-router-v6-get-path-pattern-for-current-route/71028992#71028992) and also make it compatible with **react-router v6.4+**:

```js
import { UNSAFE_RouteContext } from 'react-router-dom'

function usePathPattern() {
  let lastRouteContext = useContext(UNSAFE_RouteContext)
  while (lastRouteContext.outlet) lastRouteContext = lastRouteContext.outlet.props.routeContext
  return lastRouteContext.matches
    .map(({ route: { path } }) => path)
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join('/')
    .replaceAll(/\/\*?\//g, '/')
}
```

---

## But ...

... if you (like me) need to know *the pattern that matched until here (where `usePathPattern()` is used)*, **NOT the full-pattern**, then you don't need to traverse into route-context to find the last one (`findLastNode` in [@RichN answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265608/react-router-v6-get-path-pattern-for-current-route/71028992#71028992)).

### So this would be enough:

```js
import { UNSAFE_RouteContext } from 'react-router-dom'

function useRoutePattern() {
  const routeContext = useContext(UNSAFE_RouteContext)
  return useMemo(
    () =>
      routeContext.matches
        .map(({ route: { path } }) => path)
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join('/')
        .replaceAll(/\/\*?\//g, '/'),
    [routeContext.matches],
  )
}
```

Sample output:

```bash
 # In a near-to-root component:
/:localeCode/:orgName/
# In a very nested component (for the same URL):
/:localeCode/:orgName/iaas/:projectSlug/vms/:vmUid/
```

Answer (score 0):

I come from Blazor and c# so it is quite different. I think I will still use my own way...

here it is in typescript and using the latest version of react-router dom (V6.3.0).

Basically, I am declaring all of my private route names in an array and then just validating the user's intended path with the array.

Also notice that I am passing the isLogged param so the router knows where to redirect.

From the login component, I can later know where the user wanted to go and redirect them back there after they are logged in. (featured not implemented in this example)

```
import {useRoutes, useNavigate, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export const RouteHandler = ({isLogged} : any) : any => {
let location = useLocation();
let navigate = useNavigate();

let privateRoutes : string[] = [
    "/dashboard",
    "/products"
    //add more private stuff here
];

if(privateRoutes.includes(location.pathname))
{
    if(!isLogged)
    {
        navigate(`/login?return=${location.pathname}`);
    }
}
else
{
    //will go to not found
}

return useRoutes([
    { 
        path: "/login", 
        element: <h2>Login component</h2>
    },
    { 
        path: "/dashboard", 
        element: <h2>You are now logged in</h2>
    },
    { 
        path: "*", 
        element: <h2>Page not found</h2>
    },
]);
}
```

Here is how to use it

```
import {RouteHandler } from './mylocation';

<RouteHandler isLogged={true}/>
```

I hope that it will be useful for some folks in the future.

Comment: This won't work if pathname contains variables

Comment: hi @АндрейКозюля you have to declare your routes to accept variables. It is an example but you can simply declare the path that you need variables with and it should still work the same way. I hope that helps. Bests

Answer (score 0):

You may use `matchPath`.

```
 const { pathName } = useLocation();
    
 const currentRoute = ["/", "/messages", "/messages/:id"].find((pattern) => {
     return matchPath(pattern, pathname);
 });
```

```
const useMatchPath = (
  routes: string[],
): string | undefined => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [route, setRoute] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentRoute = routes.find((pattern) => {
      return matchPath(pattern, pathname);
    });
    setRoute(currentRoute);
  }, [pathname]);

  return route;
};
```

And use it directly inside a Component:

```
const currentRoute = useMatchPath(["/", "/messages", "/messages/:id"])
```

#### Reference:

https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/utils/match-path

---

Alternatively, you may use, `useMatch` which is a react-router hook that uses `matchPath`.

```
const useMatchRoute = (routes: string[]): string | undefined => {
  return routes.find((route) => useMatch(route));
};


const currentRoute = useMatchRoute(["/", "/messages", "/messages/:id"])
```

#### Reference:

https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/hooks/use-match

Comment: What about nested routes support?

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav className="h-auto grid space-y-5 over-x-auto overflow-y-auto">
          {navLinks.map((item, idx) => (
            <div key={idx} className="grid">
              <label className="uppercase px-5 text-gray-400 text-xs mb-2">
                {item.menu}
              </label>
              {item.submenu.map((sitem, idx) => (
                <NavLink
                  role="button"
                  key={idx}
                  to={`/${item.path}/${sitem.path}`}
                  className={({ isActive, isPending }) =>
                    isPending
                      ? "pending"
                      : isActive
                      ? "inline-flex gap-x-2 py-2 bg-gray-700 px-5 items-center w-full text-gray-300 font-medium"
                      : "inline-flex gap-x-2 py-2 hover:bg-gray-700 px-5 items-center w-full text-gray-400"
                  }
                >
                  <PiChatsLight size={20} />
                  {sitem.name}
                </NavLink>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))}
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this:

```js
// Define routes as a tree of objects
const appRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
    { path: '/whatever', element: <WhateverRouteElement/> },
    // ... other routes ...
];

// Get the current location
const location = useLocation();

// Find the route(s) that match the current location
const matchedRoutes = matchRoutes(appRoutes, location);

// If multiple routes match, assume they are parent/child routes and join
// their paths together to form the URL pattern that matched the current URL.
// If no routes matched then use '/' if the location is '/', otherwise '*'.
const urlPattern = matchedRoutes
        ?.map(({ route }) => route.path)
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join('/') || (location.pathname === '/' ? '/' : '*');
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot at this time. Here is the work around:

```
<Route path="/:state" element={<LocationView />} />
<Route path="/:state/:city*" element={<LocationView city />} />
```

I assume you're trying to render the same component under multiple paths. Instead of checking the path pattern, you can add a boolean prop to the component (in this case `city`) and check if the prop is true.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a custom hook for that purpose, since it doesn't seem to be supported oob right now:

**Note: it's not thoroughly tested yet. So use with caution.**

```
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router';

export function useRoutePathPattern() {
  const routeParams = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();

  let routePathPattern = location.pathname;

  Object.keys(routeParams)
    .filter((paramKey) => paramKey !== '*')
    .forEach((paramKey) => {
      const paramValue = routeParams[paramKey];
      const regexMiddle = new RegExp(`\/${paramValue}\/`, 'g');
      const regexEnd = new RegExp(`\/${paramValue}$`, 'g');

      routePathPattern = routePathPattern.replaceAll(
        regexMiddle,
        `/:${paramKey}/`,
      );
      routePathPattern = routePathPattern.replaceAll(regexEnd, `/:${paramKey}`);
    });

  return routePathPattern;
}
```

Comment: What if the same value is used twice in the path?

Answer (score -1):

For React-Router-Dom version 6 (v6),
Use this code:

first import 'useLocation' from RRD.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then make a constant and use it wherever needed.

```
 const currentPath = useLocation().pathname;
  console.log(currentPath);
```

Hope this will resolve your problem of getting path name in React Router Dom version 6

Comment: looks like the exact same answer already exists

Answer (score -3):

```
import { useMatch, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Element1 match={useMatch("/")} />}  >
      <Route path=":id" element={<Element2 match={useMatch("/:id")} />}  />
   </Route>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score -4):

It's not a direct answer to the question, but those, who found this question while trying to get the `params` from the `match` object, this can now be done with the `useParams` hook.

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

<Routes>
   <Route path="/:id" element={<MyComponent />} />
</Routes>

...

function MyComponent() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return <div>{id}</div>
}
```

Hope it's useful.