# React Router v6 useNavigate() doesn't navigate if replacing last element in path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react component with the following function

```
    const handleNavigate = (clientId) => {
        console.log(clientId)
        navigate(`/dashboard/clients/${clientId}`)
    }
```

The console.log() is showing the ID I want to append to use in the navigate function.
AND
The URL in the browser **is** updating.

But the page does not change.

This works to navigate from `/dashboard/clients` to `/dashboard/clients/foo`

but it does not work to navigate from `/dashboard/clients/foo` to `/dashboard/clients/bar`

The clientId is passed into the card like so...

```
const CompanyCard = (props) => {
    const { client, showWatchlist, removeDisabled, showRemove, removeType } = props
...
}
```

then in the card

```
                <CardActionArea
                    onClick={() => handleNavigate(client._id)}
                 ...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

### UPDATE

After reading up from @redapollos suggestion I tried `Outlet` and the

useRoutes methods... neither worked.

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom'

// then in the routes...

        { path: 'clientdetail/:id', element: <ClientDetail /> },
        { path: 'clientdetail/', element: <ClientDetail /> },
```

This might be due to using the `useRoutes` hook but I am still working on it.

Another question here on SO that might get an answer sooner -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70009104/13078911

Comment: Please share how you are handling the ``clientId`` change.

Comment: @programandoconro - does that help? i can verify that the `console.log(clientId)` part is logging the desired information (the clientId I want to navigate to)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just read in React Router Dom Docs v6 this solution:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
<Button onClick={() => navigate('../user', { replace: true })}>Register</Button>
```

So, basically I added `../` before the route and the `replace: true`. 
*Reference:* https://reactrouter.com/en/6.9.0/hooks/use-navigate

It worked for me, hope it works for u! (:

Answer (score 19):

## Workable solution!

```
navigate('/url')
navigate(0)
```

After replacing the url, manually calling `navigate(0)` will refresh the page automatically!

This will work in a situation like
navigate from `/same_path/foo` to `/same_path/bar`.

##### Be aware of unintended page referesh behavior:

For a normal situation like navigate from `/home` to `/same_path/bar`, `navigate(0)` will cause page to refresh even after page has finished rendering. And to prevent that, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265608/react-router-v6-get-path-pattern-for-current-route).

##### More info:

1. [useNavigate docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate)
2. [How do I reload a page with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71336494/16648127)

Comment: Hello, I've tried and it worked, but because of reloading 2 times, when I click back on Browser, it's kind of weird like first back it ok, but the second back it shows the same page.

Comment: This workaround works for me and is great but I'm curious why we need to manually refresh with `navigate(0)`? Seems a little hacky and `navigate('url')` should work out of the box. FWIW I am unable to get the wrapper `<Navigate>` to work as well and I'm suspecting this is the reason. Perhaps there's a root cause specific to our applications that should be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue and my code was fine, however, I found out at this post that optional params aren't supported in v6.
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7285

I had:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="list/:id?" element={<SystemList />} />
</Routes>
```

and had to change it to:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="list/:id" element={<SystemList />} />
  <Route path="list/" element={<SystemList />} />
</Routes>
```

I'm hoping they support it in the future but as of v6.0.2 they do not.

Comment: Good suggestion @redapollos - thank you. the issues link gave me an idea - I will post my learning here as soon as I can try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the URL instead of adding a new one. when you are going from
`/dashboard/clients` to `/dashboard/clients/foo` you are going from a parent to a child, your URL has everything plus `/foo`. But, when you are going from `/dashboard/clients/foo` to `/dashboard/clients/bar` you are navigating to a sibling `/foo` to `/bar` that might be causing the issue. try to replace the value like  `navigate(/dashboard/clients/ba, {replace: true})` here is example of how to use this in general.  use it for more information. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-router-v6

Comment: Thanks @C, unfortunately this does not have any effect. I think it makes sense that we wouldn't want to replace the current `.../foo` location in the history stack either way though. what if we wanted to navigate back to `foo` from `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the component Navigate:

```
<Navigate to={<your_path>}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late but I had the same issue and you simply just have to trigger a re-render for your component. You can do this by adding a useEffect hook within your component you have assigned `/dashboard/clients/:clientId` to with a dependency of the param you want to update.

It should look something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


const ClientDashboard = () => {

    const params = useParams()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
    //do something with new id 
    },[params.clientId])

    const handleNavigate = (clientId) => {
        navigate(`/dashboard/clients/${clientId}`)
    }

    .....
}
```

Your page should now update with the new param

Answer (score 1):

I'm using react-router-dom@^6.6.2

As of now I achieved using `../`

```html
navigate("../", {
      replace: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better work around on this one.

```
import React from 'react' 
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom' 
... 

const history = useHistory() 
const handleNavigate = (clientId) => {
        console.log(clientId)
        history.push(`/dashboard/clients/${clientId}`)
    }
```

Make sure your app is wrapped in a `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: Thanks Crispen, unfortunately v6 does not have the `useHistory()` hook. https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7476 - and even in the link you provided https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-react-router-v6#usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Answer (score 0):

Try adding window-location as key prop to the element in route

ie

```
<Route path=":id" element={ <Hello key={window.location.pathname} } />
```

Comment: There was the same issue with v5 also .

So, check. it might work.

if you already solved it could you explain it too?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8245 I could solve this issue.

I guess that as nothing has been changed the screen is not updated. As soon as I added I useEffect on the target route component and passed the lastelement as a parameter it worked.

In other words: On the target component add: Reac.useEffect(....) [lastElement].

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32144395)