# React-Router: Log the path on every route changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there any way in React-Router to console.log the path like so **"users/:userId"** (not "users/123") **from the root component** every time the route changes from anywhere in the app?

So for we have this, but can only print "users/123":

```
// ...

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
      console.log(
        `${action} ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`
      );
    });

    return () => {
      unlisten();
    };
  }, []);

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router v6: get path pattern for current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265608/react-router-v6-get-path-pattern-for-current-route)

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `match` object instead of the `location` object. `match` will have the `path` pattern string used.

[match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match)

> A match object contains information about how a `<Route path>` matched
> the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> - params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path
> - isExact - (boolean) `true` if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
> - ***path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested `<Route>`s***
> - url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested `<Link>`s

Use the [useRouteMatch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook without any arguments to return the match object of the current `<Route>`.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ path });
  }, [path]);

  // ...
}
```

This assumes that there is a router higher in the ReactTree than `App` providing a routing context.

Comment: We're looking to have a single useEffect at the root component that would match everything, so this won't work unfortunately :/

Comment: @AlexNault I see. Yeah, just tested this and it appears `useRouteMatch` can only grab matches from above itself. Can you provide a more complete code example that includes some routes?