# React Router v6: get router path with params names

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route with dynamic path, using params:

```
<Route
    path="/main/:id"
    element={
        <Page />
    }
/>
```

When I reach that page, using React Router `useLocation`, I'm able to get the full path:

```
"/main/5432gt34"
```

Is there a way to retrieve the path with the params name instead of the actual path?
(output I'm looking for is:)

```
"/main/:id"
```

I'm hoping this might be possible since React Router is aware of the params inside the path and you can extract those with `useParams`

Comment: Can you explain your use case for this, as i would have thought you only have one component for that route and therefor within the Page component you can always assume the path is "/main/:id"

Comment: Yes exactly I have a few routes such as "/main", "/main/:id" and "/main/edit" and they all point to the same component, but besides rendering that component I'd like to fetch some data, so a fixed path name such as "/main/:id" would help me, otherwise I could use regex of course but I hoped there's a native clean solution by React Router, because the downside of using regex for this is that if I change the structure of path I will need to adapt the regex function

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** You could pull the id from the string using a regex.

```js
var location = useLocation();
var myRegexp = /main\/(.*)/;
var id = myRegexp.exec(location.pathname)[1];
```

Little explanation of the regex:

- `\/` allows us to do match with "main/"
- `(.*)` gives the rest of the match as a second result in returned array.

Once you have the id you can store it a reactContext so that it can be used in any child component.

**Solution 2:** [useRouteLoaderData](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-route-loader-data#userouteloaderdata)

This solution would require you to refactor your router so that it one of the data routers but afterwards you should be able to do:

```js
const user = useRouteLoaderData("id");
```

Comment: That would only work for this specific instance,op is searching for broad solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think react router gives a way to do this but you could do something like this if you're trying to find an easy solution.

```
<Route
    path="/main"
    element={
        <Page type="index"/>
    }
/>
<Route
    path="/main/:id"
    element={
        <Page type="id"/>
    }
/>
```

then handle the type parameter in your page component.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's possible but you can always just pass it as property.

```
<Route
    path="/main/:id"
    element={
        <Page 
            path="/main/:id"
        />
    }
/>
```

Aside from that answer for this is here: [react-router v6: get path pattern for current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265608/react-router-v6-get-path-pattern-for-current-route)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by using useParams only if you know the prefix (You're sure that the path starts with "/main" and the rest is dynamic as you mentioned in your question):

```js
let params = useParams();
useEffect(() => {
  let dynamicPath = "/main";
  Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
    dynamicPath += `/:${key}`;
  });
  console.log(dynamicPath);
}, []);
```